# FastLane which branch it would use

Tags: fastlane

I am new to FastLane. And I'm trying to build our app. I did successfully able to export the IPA file of our app but I'm not sure which branch FastLane used to build the app. Would it use the Master branch? or would it use the branch I'm currently on (if I open the SourceTree and select a branch)?

I searched over the SO but I didn't found any information that could answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on how exactly you set up fastlane and your lanes of course, but by default fastlane and `build_ios_app`/`build_app`/`gym` work on the local checkout on your hard drive (so what you currently have checked out via git/Sorucetree).

You can also of course make fastlane check out a specific branch in your lane in your `Fastfile` by calling the appropriate action - pretty much anything is possible.